# golang weird beep noise when I try to print response body as a string

Tags: terminal

I am trying to print the response body in my grpc service.

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
fmt.Println(string(body))
```

As soon as the program reaches this line, my laptop starts beeping frantically. Stopping the session or killing the process isn't helping. This requires me to restart my machine.

Suppose I don't do the string conversion, then the code works just fine, it prints out the array of bytes and doesn't make any noise.

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
fmt.Println(body)
```

All the grpc service does is make an http Get request to download a file and calculate its checksum. This issue is happening when I try to download the file.

I am adding this question knowing well that this has high chances of getting downvoted, but I need to understand why this could be happening.This issue sounds extremely weird and unbelievable too, but has it happened to anyone else?

Comment: The `fmt.Println(string(body))` statement writes the response bytes as is to stdout.  There's probably something in the data that causes the terminal to beep (CTRL-G for example).  Examine the data by printing with `fmt.Printf("%q\n", body)` or by writing the data with the [hex dumper](https://godoc.org/encoding/hex#Dumper).

Comment: Thanks @ThunderCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about print if there's an error, and print the response body by skipping non-printable characters?

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %s\n", err)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", body)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ThunderCat, answer updated with your suggestion!

Comment: @ThunderCat, sorry I just saw you had the answer in comment to the question already, you should post the answer instead.

Comment: Thanks! It prints out the response now.One of the files that I am serving is in .zip format. I wonder if printing out the response of this request caused this issue.

Comment: @Aarvi - glad it stopped beeping! you are right, printing out a binary file to console could ended up in situation like this, just like when you accidentally `cat` or `type` (in DOS) a zip file would likely start beeping again ;-)